# How do you print global variables per javascript file in node.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have node.js app. I want to print all global variables and also name of .js file that defines them. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You should probably describe the use case/your purpose since it sounds impossible to do this *exactly* how you described.

Comment: This is for debugging purposes. It would be good to know the state of application(values of all variables) along with their source.

Answer (score 2):

if  `window` object is the global object & parent of all objects in client-side , `global` is the alterntive in Node.JS back-end .

Then , what you can do actually to retrieve all **global variables** (attached to `global` object) :

```
Object.keys(global).forEach((k)=> {
    console.log(`${(typeof global[k]==='function')? `"${k}" is function`:`"${k}" is object`}` )

})
```

## DEMO :

Demo on `window` because `global` is undefined in client-side .

```js
    Object.keys(window).forEach((k)=> {
        console.log(`${(typeof window[k]==='function')? `"${k}" is function`:`"${k}" is object`}` )
    
    })
```

Comment: I also want to print the source of variables (the .js file they belong to). Is this possible by extending this snippet?

Comment: @Sagar you can try to check those variables before and after including each package (manually), but there's no way to do that automatically. Unless `require` is hijackable, he-he (haven't tested yet)